# NameError. Python не видит класс

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Я учу python, в данный момент классы. Я написал простую программу (на 90% списанную с учебника), при запуске которой компилятор выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> NameError: name 'Dog' is not defined`.

Как исправить?

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    
    def bark(self):
        print("woof!")
            
    toby = Dog ("toby", "brown")        
    print("This is ", toby.name,".")
    print("It's", toby.color)
    bark()  

class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    
    def meow(self):
        print("meow")   
    felix = Cat ("felix", "white")
    print("This is ", felix.name, ".")
    print("It's", felix.color)
    meow()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В `Python` важно строго соблюдать отступы.

Я думаю, вы имеете в виду следующий код

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def bark(self):
        print("woof!")

toby = Dog ("toby", "brown")        
print("This is ", toby.name,".")
print("It's", toby.color)
bark()  

class Cat:
    def __init__(self, name, color):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color

    def meow(self):
        print("meow")

felix = Cat ("felix", "white")
print("This is ", felix.name, ".")
print("It's", felix.color)
meow()
```